# Android webRTC VideoTrack.addRenderer api change

Tags: java, android, webrtc

In all tutorials i have yet encountered the code looks like `someVideoTrack.addRenderer(new VideoRenderer(someSurfaceViewRenderer));`.

Yet, in the latest version of webRTC for android, the `VideoRenderer`-constructor looks like that:
`public VideoRenderer(VideoRenderer.Callbacks callbacks);`.

Thus, no `SurfaceViewRenderer`-parameter in sight.
Can anyone explain how to connect a SurfaceViewRenderer to a VideoTrack?

Thanks in regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not knowledgeable enough to inform you as to why this works, but I managed to get my application working by replacing

```
someVideoTrack.addRenderer(new VideoRenderer(someSurfaceViewRenderer));
```

with

```
someVideoTrack.addSink(someSurfaceViewRenderer);
```

I managed to find my answer in this thread:
[Local Video Renderer in Android WebRTC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50291497/local-video-renderer-in-android-webrtc)

Comment: Yup, you are absolutely correct. Sadly i forgot to post the answer here when i figured it out.