# CameraCapturer must be initialized before calling startCapture

Tags: java, android, webrtc, webrtc-android

Facing this issue while implementing **WebRTC** in Android:

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: CameraCapturer must be initialized before calling startCapture.

**build.gradle(:app)**

```
dependencies {
  ......
  implementation 'org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.+'
  ......
}
```

// Chunk causing problem:

```
private void getVideoSource() {
    // isScreenCast = false
    videoSource = peerConnectionFactory.createVideoSource(false);
    surfaceTextureHelper = SurfaceTextureHelper.create(Thread.currentThread().getName(), rootEglBase.getEglBaseContext());
    VideoCapturer videoCapturer = createCameraCapturer(new Camera1Enumerator(false));
    localVideoTrack = peerConnectionFactory.createVideoTrack("200", videoSource);
    localVideoTrack.addSink(local_renderer);
    if(videoCapturer != null)
        videoCapturer.startCapture(1000,1000,30); // <- Here is the Exception

}
```

[CameraCapturer](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+/lkgr/sdk/android/src/java/org/webrtc/CameraCapturer.java) is deprecated. There is **Camera1Capturer** now available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You need to initialise before you use it

```
 private void getVideoSource() {
    VideoCapturer videoCapturer = createVideoCapturer();
    VideoSource videoSource;
    //Create a VideoSource instance
    if (videoCapturer != null) {
        SurfaceTextureHelper surfaceTextureHelper = SurfaceTextureHelper.create("CaptureThread", rootEglBase.getEglBaseContext());
        videoSource = factory.createVideoSource(videoCapturer.isScreencast());
        videoCapturer.initialize(surfaceTextureHelper, this, videoSource.getCapturerObserver());
    }
   

    localVideoTrack = factory.createVideoTrack("100", videoSource);

    //Create MediaConstraints - Will be useful for specifying video and audio constraints.
    audioConstraints = new MediaConstraints();
    videoConstraints = new MediaConstraints();

    //create an AudioSource instance
    audioSource = factory.createAudioSource(audioConstraints);
    localAudioTrack = factory.createAudioTrack("101", audioSource);

    if (videoCapturer != null) {
        videoCapturer.startCapture(1024, 720, 30);
    }
    binding.localGlSurfaceView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    // And finally, with our VideoRenderer ready, we
    // can add our renderer to the VideoTrack.
    localVideoTrack.addSink(binding.localGlSurfaceView);
}
```

Comment: thanks. Can you guide me how to use device public IP  address (assume I have it from STUN Server) and save it in `SessionDescription`?

Comment: Not yet... I am still wandering how to do simple P2P Video Chat without involving any server. Though I am using Firebase Messaging for sending offer and answer. But that also not completed yet.

Comment: ok, let me share some code. I will share you github link. I recently did this work. We have one public server

Comment: @FaizanMubasher : My demo will take time to complete but you can check this https://github.com/IhorKlimov/Android-WebRtc

Comment: Thanks! Much appreciated

Comment: Kotlin example -> https://github.com/ShwetaChauhan18/WebRTC-Android

Comment: Need help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58429603/onicecandidate-is-never-call-after-setremotedescription-webrtc-android